# How to determine details of backgound process?

Tags: macos, settings, login-items, multitasking

In my system settings on macOS Sonoma I see a bunch of apps in the "Allow in Background" for example in the screenshot there are there are several entries for Docker. How do I find out exactly what process corresponds to each icon?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a small helper script that parses `sfltool` output with `awk` and formats it in a digestible way. This may help you determine what those specific background apps are.

More details at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/luckman212/login-items-dump).

*excerpt showing partial output:*

```
Name                                                       BundleID                               URL                                                                                                ExecPath
Alfred 5.app                                               com.runningwithcrayons.Alfred          file:///Applications/Alfred%205.app/                                                               -
Bartender (Surtees Studios Limited)                        com.surteesstudios.Bartender-setapp    file:///Applications/Setapp/Bartender.app/                                                         -
CCC Dashboard (Bombich Software, Inc.)                     com.bombich.cccdashboard               file:///Applications/Carbon%20Copy%20Cloner.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/CCC%20Dashboard.app/   -
CleanShot X (Make The Web Oślizło & Magiera s.c.)          com.getcleanshot.app-setapp            file:///Applications/Setapp/CleanShot%20X.app/                                                     -
Hammerspoon.app                                            org.hammerspoon.Hammerspoon            file:///Applications/Hammerspoon.app/                                                              -
Hyperduck                                                  com.sindresorhus.Hyperduck             file:///Applications/Hyperduck.app/                                                                -
LaunchControl (Robby Pahlig)                               com.soma-zone.LaunchControl            file:///Applications/LaunchControl.app/                                                            -
Microsoft Teams (work or school) (Microsoft Corporation)   com.microsoft.teams2                   file:///Applications/Microsoft%20Teams%20(work%20or%20school).app/                                 -
Microsoft Teams Launcher (Microsoft Corporation)           com.microsoft.teams2.launcher          Contents/Library/LoginItems/Microsoft%20Teams%20Launcher.app                                       -
Pareto Security (Niteo GmbH)                               niteo.co.Pareto                        file:///Applications/Pareto%20Security.app/                                                        -
PixelSnap (Make The Web Oślizło & Magiera s.c.)            pl.maketheweb.pixelsnap2-setapp        file:///Applications/Setapp/PixelSnap.app/                                                         -
Proxyman                                                   com.proxyman.NSProxy-setapp            file:///Applications/Setapp/Proxyman.app/                                                          -
SecretAgent (Max Goedjen)                                  com.maxgoedjen.Secretive.SecretAgent   Contents/Library/LoginItems/SecretAgent.app                                                        -
Secretive (Max Goedjen)                                    com.maxgoedjen.Secretive.Host          file:///Applications/Secretive.app/                                                                -
com.ninxsoft.mist.helper (Nindi Gill)                    -                                      file:///Library/LaunchDaemons/com.ninxsoft.mist.helper.plist                                       /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.ninxsoft.mist.helper
com.proxyman.NSProxy.HelperTool (TablePlus Inc)          -                                      file:///Library/LaunchDaemons/com.proxyman.NSProxy.HelperTool.plist                                /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.proxyman.NSProxy.HelperTool
```

*Here's the command used to generate the neatly-formatted columnar output above:*

```
( printf "Name\tBundleID\tURL\tExecPath\n"; login-items-dump | cut -d$'\t' -f2- ) | column -s$'\t' -t
```